# Buffer Overflow - Discarding packets unicast vs broadcast

Tags: buffer, broadcast, buffer-overflow

I have a small confusion and curiosity.

When a buffer is full, ***How does the respective OSI layer start removing packets? Does it discriminate between broadcasts vs unicasts***?

(For specifics if required, 802.11g and 802.15.4)

I remember reading in some paper that it starts with discarding unicasts packets first. But i can't find some credible source on the subject.

Thank you for your time.

Best regards,
Rehan

***Context***
I am trying to highlight the inherent differences between how broadcast packets are handled vs unicasts. Namely:

1) Unlike Unicast packets, Broadcast packets don't require RTS/CTS

2) Unlike Unicast packets, Broadcast packets don't require a destination address

3) In an event of full buffer,... ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you referring to the MAC layer, as in layer 2 in the OSI model?  If so, why the OSX tag?  And if you meant Mac as in OS X and Apple, then are you referring to layer 2 broadcasts or layer 3?  And if layer 3, I assume you're talking about IP?  And, can you link to *any* source you read that says this, credible or not?  Some context would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Brad, the tag for "OS X" got added by mistake (removed now). My question is related to OSI model's layer 2.  I have also updated the context. Thanks.